# Delay in Authentication in Nuxt3 + Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Currently I'm diving deeper into Nuxt3 and Firebase Authentication. I've successfully implemented Firebase Authentication in my project and can register / login a new user.

When the user is successfully logged in - for testing purposes - I want to show the firebase user details. When the user is not logged in he or she should see a login form.

When I hit F5 (reload page) I'm seeing the login form and after 2-3 seconds its hiding the login form and displaying the NuxtPage. In that case I could just display a loading spinner until Nuxt has loaded the real logged in state, but for example if I have a menu where the username is displayed when the user is already logged in, how could I solve this without displaying an not-logged-in-menu entry first?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^18",
    "nuxt": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.22.2"
  }
}
```

In my app.vue (homepage) I got the following code:

```
<div v-if="!firebaseUser">
    <div>
        LOGIN FORM
    </div>
</div>

<NuxtPage v-if="firebaseUser" />

<script setup>
    const firebaseUser = useFirebaseUser();
    ...
</script>
```

composables/useStats.ts:

```
export const useFirebaseUser = () => useState("firebaseUser", () => null);
```

composables/useFirebase.ts:

```
export const initUser = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const firebaseUser = useFirebaseUser();
    firebaseUser.value = auth.currentUser;

    const router = useRouter();

    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
        if (user) {
                    ...
        } else {
            router.push("/");
        }

        firebaseUser.value = user;
    });
};
```

I think my problem is that I need to find a solution to check if the user is logged in before the page is displayed/drawn. But I have no idea on how to do that. Is that even possible?